# Сохранение данных с XML файла в Локальном Хранилище

Tags: javascript, html

Я делаю веб-читалку и распарсил ФБ2 файл. С выведением на страницу HTML нет никаких проблем, а как сделать так, чтобы сейвился и прогресс чтения пользователем и сами данные, распарсенные с файла в Локальном Хранилище? Пример получения прикреплен ниже и довольно прост.

```
file.addEventListener('change', async function (event) {
const file = event.target.files[0] || {};

const fileResult = view.querySelector('p').innerHTML = await file.text();
}
```